# Wechat social meta tags

Tags: meta-tags, wechat

I just got a requirement from my client to have social meta tags for sharing with WeChat, and I couldn't find any document related to this, maybe it was write in chinese. Anyone know what they use?

Comment: Apparently this currently just isn't possible. At least not in an official way.